# what is the purpose of atexit function?

Tags: unix

I know when the address of the function is passed to `atexit` function,
the function is excuted.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int atexit(void (*func) void));
```

However, what is the **purpose** of using `atexit` function?

Does verbal meaning itself 'exit' relate to `atexit` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atexit` would be used for some code that you want to execute when the application terminates, regardless of where it was exited from. One example would be an application-wide logger. You would call `atexit(flush_log)`, so when the application exits, the log will be flushed, without the developer having to remember to flush it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `atexit` is related to `exit`.

`exit` can call functions which are automatically called before a program exits. These functions are called *exit handlers* and are registered by calling `atexit` function.

```
#include<stdio.h>                 

main(void) {                        
atexit(func);
}

func(void) 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int atexit(void (*func)(void));
```

The above declaration says that we pass the address of a function as the argument to `atexit`. When this function is called, it is not passed any arguments and is not expected to return a value. The exit function called these functions in reverse order of their registration. Each function is called as many times as they registered.