# What would you use an exit handler for?

Tags: c, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the purpose of atexit function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691429/what-is-the-purpose-of-atexit-function)

In UNIX at least: I'm aware that C/C++ can register a number of functions to be called at the exit of main - exit handlers.  Thee functions to be called can be registered, in reverse order, using:

```
int atexit(void (*func) (void));
```

I'm having trouble determining how this would be useful though.  The functions are void/void and global, so they are unlikely to have access to many variables around the program unless the variables are also globals.  Can someone let me know the kinds of things you would do with exit handlers?

Also, do exit handlers work the same way on non-UNIX platforms since they're part of an ANSI C specification?

Comment: For freeing memory. Ho wait. Good question!

Comment: Examples of where it's useful: 1) Generated code (think `atexit(run_static_destructors);`) 2) Example code (`atexit(SDL_Quit);`) 3) Interfacing with code that calls `exit` behind your back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform cleanup for global objects in a `atexit` handler:

```
static my_type *my_object;

static void my_object_release() { free(my_object); }

my_type *get_my_object_instance() 
{
    if (!my_object)
    {
        my_object = malloc(sizeof(my_type));
        ...
        atexit(my_object_release);
    }

    return my_object;
}
```

If you want to be able to close over some variables in an atexit-like handler, you can devise your own data structure containing cleanup function/parameter pairs, and register a single atexit handler calling all the said functions with their corresponding arguments.

Comment: Looking back at my answer, I realize that since the OS cleans up the memory at program exit, you don't need `atexit` for such things. However, it is useful for other resources, like closing network connections, cleaning up temp files, saving program state, etc. In my opinion the answer by @AProgrammer is a better one.

Comment: you are probably right, free ing should not be required since the program already terminates and *frees* everything, am I not right?

Comment: @turmuka: Yes, memory is returned and open files are closed. However there are other stuff you may want to do at program exit. Closing files while checking for IO errors (tricky in general), or properly closing remote connections, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Exit handler allows a library to do shutdown cleanup (thus of global data structure) without the main program being aware of that need. Two examples of things I've done in an exit handler:

- restoring tty flags
- closing correctly a network connection so that the peer hadn't to wait a time out

Your probably can think of other use.

Comment: atexit could be used for closing network connections for stability then.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problem that an `atexit` handler solves, is tidy up for global objects. This is a C feature and of course C doesn't have automatic deallocation like C++. If you have access to the implementation of `main` you can write your own such code, but otherwise `atexit` can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, one more question though - is it still helpful in C++ or is it somewhat deprecated?

Comment: No, I think you can use RAII in C++. `atexit` is very un-C++.

Comment: There are "valid" uses for `atexit` in C++. Releasing a singleton instance is one.

Answer (score 1):

Read this blog post on [Start and Termination in C++](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/356786_start-and-termination-in-c):

> When a program is terminating it needs to do some finishing touches
>   like saving data to a file that will be used in the next session. In
>   this light each program has a particular set of things to do depending
>   on the purpose of the program (when closing). Any of such things done
>   is done by one of the functions whose pointer would be argument to the
>   atexit function.
>
> The **purpose of the `atexit` function** is to register (record in memory)
>   the functions for these finishing touches. When the atexit function
>   executes using any of the pointers to these functions as argument the
>   pointed function is registered. This has to be done before the C++
>   program reaches its termination phase.

Read more: http://www.bukisa.com/articles/356786_start-and-termination-in-c#ixzz1WdWVl4TF